# Broadband dongle is not working after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, network-manager, huawei

I upgraded 12.10 to 13.04 and my USB dongle is not recognized by network-manager. I using Huawei E367.

Modem is properly recognized by the system.

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:00a4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2880 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

However I cannot see my dongle in network manager.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

If you have similar issue, just install modemmanager.